# Download from URL (PATH) - iPhone

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, url, path

I got a little Question.

I'm working on an App, and for that I have to download an HTML File with the including CSS and Images.
And Yeah, there's an API for that (`ASIHTTPRequest`), but I wan't to publish my App to the App Store and I don't want to use 3rd party API's.
And Parsing the HTML code is a bit hard :(

And It would also work for me, if I could download the whole path of a URL.

For example:
I have this URL: `http://example.org/smthg/`.

At this path I have:

-index.html

-logo.png

-style.css

And I want to download all this files AUTOMATICALLY, and not every single file.
But I don't think, that you can find out which files are on the server, right? (without BruteForce).

I hope you know what I mean :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UIWebView to download the content at the location and hold on to the WebView.  You could also use NSURLConnection to download content at a URL if you want to save it unformatted and you have the URL's to the resources.

Comment: Downloading the Content of an UIWebView is not that what I need ;(
However, thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with using 3rd party frameworks, as long as they're good quality frameworks and you use them right. ; ) Apple just gives you the starting blocks to make an app, after all, and using open-source code can really speed up your project.

With that said, `ASIHTTPRequest` is a bit outdated and not well maintained. Instead, I'd recommend `AFNetworking`, which supports asynchronous downloads, background downloads, and blocks. See https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking .

Regarding your specific issue on downloading certain files, however, you might try creating a **plist(s)** on the server (if its yours that is, or else, bundled within the app perhaps) that would list all of the needed files and their download locations.

However, the issue you're liking going to quickly face- even if your app has all needed files downloaded, it still has to understand what to do with them. If its just HTML content, styles, etc, perhaps you can display it in a `UIWebView` ? However, be sure that your app is adding some useful functionality besides just being a web browser... (unless, of course, you're making an enhanced web browser... ;)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!
The Problem with 3rd Party frameworks is, that it is not made by me and I do not know if the frameworks will be updated. 

So I like to code everything by myself :)
I thought about **plists** to, but it would be better otherwise. But I'll make that thanks!

Saving the content of an UIWebView is also not working, because I need more then one html file.

It is a completely different App, not a Browser or anything like that :)
I just need to download those things in the App :)


THANKS :)

Comment: The benefit to using *good* 3rd party frameworks is that you save a lot of time- both coding and **debugging** time- as many people are typically working on it. It may also include ideas/code that you wouldn't have thought of yourself. You're right that some frameworks may not be active, but on the flip side, if it's open source, you have the code and can change it if needed. (Hence, the purpose of *forking* a repo... do signup for Github if you haven't already. :) If this answers your question, please accept it. Otherwise, let me know, and I'll see if I can edit my answer to better help. ;)